# Android: Set the background of listview text

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, colors, background

I need to make background for some text ir rows like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX1yM.png) How can I change the code to make this happen?

Do I need to extend another base adapter for list view, and if so how should I do this?

**Code:**

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


       View grid;
       if(convertView==null){
        grid = new View(context);
        grid = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null); 
       }else{
        grid = (View)convertView; 
       }

       ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.gridimage);

       TextView textView = (TextView)grid.findViewById(R.id.gridtext);
       imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
       textView.setText(mStringIds[position]);

       return grid; 
      }


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.grid_list_view); //lv is global
        lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    Intent sam = new Intent(CategoriesActivity.this, CategoriesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(sam);
                    System.out.println("on item click");

                }
        });

      public void makeList(String value) {

            String prekes_pav = null;   
            int prekes_kiekis = 0;


            switch (position) {
                case 0: 
                    prekes_pav = "fr_veg";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    prekes_pav = "meat_fish";
                    break;
                default:
                    prekes_pav = "No name";

            }
            if(listas.listContain("fr_veg"))
            {
                ///////// MAKE text background BLUE
            }

            listas.createItem(prekes_pav, value, null);
            simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, listas.getList(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {prekes_pav}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
            lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);  
        }
```

**Grid xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">
 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/gridimage"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="40dp"/>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/gridtext"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:textSize="16dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Grid window xml**

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="265dp"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="15dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_blue_gradient"
/>
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/cat_button_slide"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="60dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center"

     android:background="@drawable/tongue_down"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />

 <ListView android:id="@+id/grid_list_view" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What attribute it your xml do you want changed?

Comment: grid_list_view row's text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reason to build a new adapter. If I misunderstood what you are trying to do, let me know and I will try to help.

There are two ways to do it. One By xml, and one by java:

Inside Grid window.xml

```
  <ListView android:id="@+id/grid_list_view" 
          android:background="#0000ff"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
/>
```

Or by code:

```
  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.grid_list_view); //lv is global
  lv..setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
  lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
```

Comment: This will change the whole list view background. I need to change only specific listview item text background. For example here is first list item with blue background, 2-5 with white background, 6th has blue background and  so on -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/bX1yM.png ... The backround should be changed in place: 

if(listas.listContain("fr_veg"))
            {
                ///////// MAKE text background BLUE
            }

Is it possible? :)

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe this? http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Answer (score 1):

Change your grid.xml's to include to something like this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#BBBBBB" />
```

Comment: This will chane the text background blow the icons (aple, chicken, etc.), And I need to change background where the red arrow is (I need in some list elements  to be blue background and the other should have white) http://i.stack.imgur.com/bX1yM.png